# iPhone not honoring CSS Grid Rows

Tags: css, iphone, css-grid

```
.remote-local-video {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.25rem;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 80vh;
  grid-template-areas: "remoteVideo localVideo";

  .ch-video {
    object-fit: contain;
  }

  @media (max-width: 769px) {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 40vh 40vh;
    grid-template-areas: "remoteVideo" "localVideo";
  }
}
```

We have this CSS. It seems to be working fine in Android Chrome, Chrome/Firefox dev tools in Macbook Pro. In iPhone 12 Max Pro, iPhone 11 Pro and IPhone XR - either remoteVideo is displayed or localVideo is displayed. Both are not displayed together. I tried this both in Chrome and Safari browser.

Comment: I loved this question language "not honoring" haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.remote-local-video {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.25rem;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: calc(100vh - 80px);
  grid-template-areas: "remoteVideo localVideo";

  .ch-video {
    object-fit: contain;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 950px) and  (orientation: portrait) {
    div#meetingLocalVideo {
      height: calc(50vh - 40px);
    }

    div#meetingRemoteVideos {
      height: calc(50vh - 40px);
    }

    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: calc(50vh - 40px) calc(50vh - 40px);
    grid-template-areas: "remoteVideo" "localVideo";
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 950px) and  (orientation: landscape) {

    div#meetingLocalVideo {
      height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    }

    div#meetingRemoteVideos {
      height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    }
    grid-template-rows: calc(100vh - 80px);
  }
}
```

IOS expects us to set explicit height of divs. Above CSS is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Safari on iPhone is more particular with having perfect code than any other platform. Could it be that the closing bracket for your class .remote-local-video is at the bottom of this CSS instead of above the .ch-video class? Also (not sure if you are just using different syntax than I am used to - but I usually separate the media query and re-state the class name within). I threw this in my testing environment real quick and found it working in Safari on iPhone 6:

```
.remote-local-video {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.25rem;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 80vh;
  grid-template-areas: "remoteVideo localVideo";
}

  .ch-video {
    object-fit: contain;
  }
  

  @media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
    .remote-local-video {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 40vh 40vh;
    grid-template-areas: "remoteVideo" "localVideo";
    }
  }
```

Note: I also used the following HTML (please pardon my inline border for visibility):

```
<div class="remote-local-video">
  <div style="border: 1px solid black">1</div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid black">2</div>
</div>
```

(I once found a missing closing bracket in a JavaScript selector that was working everywhere else in a web application, but stopped working/showed up when the dept. switched to using iPhones!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I feel its better practice to encapsulate the CSS together for better maintenance. I am not the CSS expert though:)